# IMS to SCORM Conversion

Tags: scorm, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I have to develop a tool for automatic conversion from one E-learning standard Content Package to another, as of now I've considered IMS and SCORM but I didn't completely understand what could be the best reason for developing an automatic conversion tool from IMS to SCORM or vice-versa. I mean what benefits can one avail from such tool? This is the reason which I've got in one technical paper. Can anyone please explain and clarify this or tell me some good reason behind developing such a tool:

> "IMS [6] and SCORM [7] specications share many of their
>   characteristics but also have some key differences in the
>   representation of the structure of the learning content. Other
>   important issue to be considered is the extension of these systems and
>   the huge number of organizations that use them. This situation leads
>   to the fact that the same contents are created, maintained, modied
>   and so on [8]. These are usually not identical copies, but the
>   contents are the same and aim to the same learning objective. So it
>   would be useful to share the work among the organization to avoid
>   repeating the work over and over again. This would save time and
>   resources and would lead to high quality contents. The main obstacle
>   to get this is the, previously presented, existence of different types
>   of models for contents. From all of this, we can infer the utility of
>   automatic conversion between formats. This conversion will allow the
>   interaction between learning platforms at a high level of automa-
>   tion." - E-LEARNING CONTENTS AUTOMATIC CONVERSION By Guiterrez, Jose Maria et al.

**JavaScript(SCORM Package)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
var numQuestions = 2;
var rawScore = 0;
var actualScore = 0;
var question0;
var question1;
var key0 = 0;
var key1 = 1;
function getAnswer()
        {
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.id","key0b8");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.type","choice");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                          "0");

            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question0 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].value;
                  doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.student_response",question0);
                  break;
               }
            }

            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.id","key1b8");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.type","choice");
            doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                          "1");

            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question1 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].value;
                  doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.student_response",question1);
                  break;
               }
            }

           }
        function calcRawScore(){

            if (question0 == key0)
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","correct");
               rawScore++;
            }
            else
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","wrong");
            }
            if (question1 == key1)
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","correct");
               rawScore++;
            }
            else
            {
               doLMSSetValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","wrong");
            }
        }
        function calcScore2()
        {
           computeTime();  // the student has stopped here.
           document.getElementById("quizForm8").submitB.disabled = true;
           getAnswer();
           calcRawScore();
           actualScore = Math.round(rawScore / numQuestions * 100);
        alert("Your score is " + actualScore + "%")   
           doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.score.raw", actualScore+"" );
           var mode = doLMSGetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_mode" );
               if ( mode != "review"  &&  mode != "browse" ){
                 if ( actualScore < 50 )
                 {
                   doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_status", "failed" );
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                   doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.lesson_status", "passed" );
                 }
                 doLMSSetValue( "cmi.core.exit", "" );
                 } 
         exitPageStatus = true;
         doLMSCommit();
         doLMSFinish();
        }
]]>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <!-- Other Code -->
      <body>
        <div id="outer">
          <div class="QuizTestIdevice" id="id8">
            <script src="calculate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <form name="quizForm8" id="quizForm8" action="javascript:calcScore2();">
              <div class="iDevice_inner">
                <div class="passrate" value="50"></div>
                <div class="question">
                  <div id="taquestion0b8">
                    1&gt; TEXT FOR QUESTION 1.
                  </div><br />
                  True<input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="0" id="taoptionAnswer0q0b8" /> 
                  False<input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="1" id="taoptionAnswer1q0b8" />
                </div><br />
                <div class="question">
                  <div id="taquestion1b8">
                    2&gt; TEXT FOR QUESTION 2.
                  </div><br />
                  True<input type="radio" name="key1b8" value="0" id="taoptionAnswer0q1b8" /> 
                  False<input type="radio" name="key1b8" value="1" id="taoptionAnswer1q1b8" />
                </div><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submitB" value="SUBMIT ANSWERS" />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Javascript and HTML for IMS Package**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="QuizTestIdevice" id="id8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //<![CDATA[
var numQuestions = 4;
var rawScore = 0;
var actualScore = 0;
var question0;
var question1;
var key0 = 0;
var key1 = 1;
var key2 = 0;
var key3 = 0;
function getAnswer()
        {
            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question0 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key0b8[i].value;
                  break;
               }
            }

            for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
            {
               if (document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].checked)
               {
                  question1 = document.getElementById("quizForm8").key1b8[i].value;
                  break;
               }
            }
            }
        function calcRawScore(){

            if (question0 == key0)
            {
               rawScore++;
            }
            if (question1 == key1)
            {
               rawScore++;
            }
        }

        function calcScore2()
        {
            getAnswer();

            calcRawScore();
            actualScore =  Math.round(rawScore / numQuestions * 100);
            document.getElementById("quizForm8").submitB.disabled = true;
            alert("Your score is " + actualScore + "%")

        }
//]]>    -->
    </script>
<form name="quizForm8" id="quizForm8" action="javascript:calcScore2();">
<div class="iDevice emphasis1">
<img alt="" class="iDevice_icon" src="icon_question.gif" />
<span class="iDeviceTitle">SCORM Quiz</span>
<div class="iDevice_inner">
<div class="passrate" value="50"></div>
<div class="question">
<div id="taquestion0b8" class="block" style="display:block">1&gt; QUESTION 1

</div><br/>
<table><tr><td><input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="0" />
</td><td>
<div id="taoptionAnswer0q0b8" class="block" style="display:block">True

</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="key0b8" value="1" />
</td><td>
<div id="taoptionAnswer1q0b8" class="block" style="display:block">False
</div>
<br/><input type="submit" name="submitB" value="SUBMIT ANSWERS"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanking you!

Answer (score 1):

When I create hand-coded courses I try to keep everything as neutral as possible. eLearning standards, such as SCORM, are usually using what we call a "wrapper", it basically handles all basic errors and the connection process.

When you go from one version to another, like SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004 4th Edition, the logic doesn't really change, it is improved but all the previous elements are usually here.
So you basically make a new wrapper that has the same functions' names and all the basics are already working. And your wrapper is not fundamentally different, it just replaces the "cmi.xxx".

To go from one standard to another, if the fundamentals are the same, you could use another wrapper and it would work. It is usually the case for most simple courses, as soon as you start having interactions, exercises and so on, it can become tricky.
To avoid those bad moments, keep all your interactions logic seperate from your course.

Now, your course is probably not hand-coded and generated by a software?
In such case you will need to analyze what's "under the hood", trying to figure what is done when and how to replace it with the other standard's way of handling each part.

I think a converter is something very unsafe to do, it would be very course-dependent and cannot be applied to all courses the same, unless you find a way to simply replace it's interactions with a wrapper. But if you can provide a tool that can generate a course compatible with all standards, you'll already make a lot of users happy!

Now to get back to your question, I think you need to understand **what are eLearning standards made of** :

- **Files** to be displayed in the browser.
- A **manifest** file to describe the content you're giving to the LMS.
- A way of **communication** between the course and its LMS.

The files are usually HTML pages and everything that goes around. The manifest is an file usually written with XML. The communication is in most cases setup with Javascript.

- **IMS is a standard at the manifest level, it describes what should be in your .xml file.**
- **SCORM is a standard that takes into account the two last items of the list.** (based on AICC, it defines what both the course and the LMS need to comply to.)

Now if you need to create a **tool to convert the XML file**, I think any technology would be able to do it, as it is technically just plain text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes my content is generated by a software called 'Exe-Learning'. I've converted the generated package from IMS to SCORM by using XSLT,JAXP and Swing and it is working fine but as you said its a course dependent so I think here I'm facing problem. I generated a quiz and exported as IMS content package then I exported the same quiz as SCORM1.2 and by using my generated tool I converted the entire IMS package to SCORM one successfully but I didn't understand that at users level there is no difference between both the packages. So how beneficial conversion is?

Comment: Does the presence of 'sco' and additional ECMAScripts make any difference in the performance of SCORM over IMS and also some LMS (e.g. SLK) don't support IMS, so can the conversion be beneficial in this case? Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: It will make the most differences in the reporting of results, if you split your content into multiple SCOs your LMS will be able to generate data for each of them. As a practical example, let's say you have a quiz of 10 questions, and each question is a sco, you would be able to see a score for each question, plus an automatically calculated final score. It would be bad practice for such a small quiz of course.

Comment: Well in practice nowadays everything is SCORM if you work with corporate clients. It can be launched from almost any LMS, even Sharepoint could use SCORM packages, SAP, etc. New projects starts to come to life, such as http://tincanapi.com. But since you seem to be focused mainly on the "packaging" part and not the most advanced specific courses (which can only be used by scripting), it is maybe seeing too far. The main problem with SCORM is that it works well with courseware and assessments, but reach its limits when you start thinking "team learning" or serious games.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Well I want to ask regarding your penultimate comment as you said that I can generate the final quiz score if I use 'sco', so for that I need to use a javascript for calculating the score. Please see I've updated the question with the Javascript and my HTML page.

Comment: But is it possible to add this Javascript and its corresponding attributes in the output HTML file to make this calculation part work. Since, this javascript is not generalized one, so I'm doubtful about this and also its difficult to add the attributes like value="0" and value="1" in every HTML page at the specific location.

Comment: Well you used cmi.interactions which is way much better than SCOs for such things. You would use SCOs in a larger scope, for example to divide your course into a few independent lessons. Then you can use the exact same code as in a single-sco course (each SCO is an html page), each lesson would have a final score and a time spent, etc. It is then your LMS' job to display an average score and full time spent for the whole course/package.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually in my case I have multiple lessons so I face problem when I use the above Javascript because in this Javascript form name, ids and other attributes are fixed and they work only for the particular one HTML page.

Comment: As you have told that by using SCO, the exact same code can be used as in a single 'sco' course for calculating the time and score. Can you please guide me in this matter in a bit more detail that how to achieve this, do I need to write a different Javascript for this?

Comment: In first case,I created a True-False quiz and exported as IMS package as well as SCORM package and after uploading on Moodle in both the cases it tells me 'Correct' or 'Incorrect' just after clicking on the radio button. Although SCORM package has differences in manifest file, XML Schema and ECMAScript but still there is no difference at users point of view and it doesn't tell the score or time as there is no submit button. So in this case I didn't find it beneficial from going IMS to SCORM.

Comment: While in second case I created the same quiz as a 'SCORM Quiz'(there is an option for that in exe-learning) and exported as IMS and SCORM package and in this case it returns me score after clicking on submit button. So I thought it would be beneficial if I could convert case-1 IMS package to case-2 SCORM package and for that I wrote an XSLT but my XSLT is limited only for the particular quiz which I have generated because I cannot insert the same Javascript for calculation and its attributes to every HTML page.

Comment: Please see I have updated in the question.I've added the HTML page of IMS package and it also calculates and returns the score after submitting but it doesn't have ECMAScript added and manifest file also doesn't have any 'sco' in it. So in this case when even without having any SCO or ECMAScript I can get the score then why to have SCORM type? Please clarify. I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't have ECMAScript"? They both have javascript functions, which is ECMAScript. If you meant it's not using the SCORM communication (the cmi.foo strings), then yes. But I still don't understand what you mean with IMS, are you using QTI? which version? Yes QTI allows you to create a simple assessment, but SCORM goes way beyond that and can be used for many things. QTI is xml only, SCORM's purpose is to create your own course as you want it to be, not only a quiz. SCORM manifest also allows you to transfer part of the logic and calculation to the LMS if you trust it.

Comment: Thanks. Well sorry by saying "it doesn't have ECMAScript",I meant to say it doesn't have ECMAScript named 'SCOFunctions.js' and 'APIWrapper.js', which SCORM package has apart from other common javascript between these two.

Comment: In 'Exe-Learning' tool there are options for creating a quiz like 'True-False' 'Multiple Choice' 'SCORM Quiz' and after creating it you can export as IMS Content Package,SCORM1.2,Common Cartridge but they haven't specified whether its QTI or not.So what I do is after creating True-False Quiz and SCORM Quiz I export as IMS package and SCORM1.2.